# Is there a non manual way to convert pairs of delete/add changes to a move?

Tags: tfs

Is there a way either within VS2010, at the commandline, with a third party tool (preferably free), or with a script of some sort (Powershell?) to convert (within Pending Changes) a delete and add of a file to be a move instead so as to keep history intact?

Comment: Are the files completely unmodified?

Comment: Almost all of them are modified.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I need this too.

Answer (score 0):

Pending Changes means that the source control changes you have made are not committed to TFS. Therefore, the history has not been altered by the pending delete or pending add.

If you wanted the history to reflect a move, you should undo your pending change and create it as a move operation by using Source Control Explorer. Right-click on the file and select Move...

Comment: Sounds as unpleasant as SVN. In Hg there is a way to "annotate a move after the fact" (but before the commit), no such love for TFS?

Comment: Ideally, I would like a way to loop through the transactions in the pending changes, match up corresponding delete/adds for a file, remove those two transactions and add a 'move' transaction based on the two paths from the delete and add. I'm moving and 'fixing up' many files in a code reorganization effort. Perhaps this is doable with tf.exe, but I'm not seeing anything obvious yet. @Novus, I'd prefer not to do it the way you suggest.

Comment: @user166390 - you can actually do just that in SVN.  You select both the add and the delete, right-click one of them and select "Rename".  I haven't done this for years, but I used to do that all the time.